# Which version of Visual Studio / MSDN subscription required to develop BizTalk applications

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, biztalk, msdn, biztalk-2010

- Which version of Visual Studio/MSDN subscription required to develop
  on BizTalk?
- Pro is sufficient or Enterprise is required and what is
  the difference?
- Does Visual Studio 2015 works with BizTalk 2010?

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/4/15454442-CF17-47B9-A65D-DF84EF88511B/Products_by_Benefit_Level.xlsx

Comment: Thank you Hans, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is available at MSDN.

MSDN Enterprise is required to access all of the Server apps.

BizTalk Server 2010 requires Visual Studio 2010.